# Generate select list from external JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, select

I am trying to generate a select menu from a JSON file based upon an initial selection. I've seen so many different ways that people have written a function for this but want something that is very simple.

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="beta-filter1" data-set="default" data-select="practise">
    <option label="Please select" value="">Please select</option>
    <option label="Practise one" value="Practise one">Practise one</option>
    <option label="Practise two" value="Practise three">Practise two</option>
    <option label="Practise three" value="Practise three">Practise three</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="beta-filter2" data-set="default" data-select="law" disabled>
    <option label="Please select" value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Practise one": [
        {"area": "Acquisition and Leveraged Finance"},
        {"area": "Asset-Based Lending"},
        {"area": "Bankruptcy"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Practise two": [
        {"area": "Corporate Governence"},
        {"area": "Derivatives"},
        {"area": "High Yield Offerings"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Practise three": [
        {"area": "Electric Power Regulation"},
        {"area": "Export Control"},
        {"area": "FCPA"}
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to use data from an external JSON file. Practise 1/2/3 are from the initial select then the areas are for the generated options. Apologies if very vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed some redundancy from your JSON to try and further simplify your code. You could simplify it further by changing, for instance, `{"area": "Electric Power Regulation"}` to simply `"Electric Power Regulation"`, then `{text:this.area,value:this.area}` would change to `{text:this,value:this}`.

```js
var options = {
    "Practise one": [
        {"area": "Acquisition and Leveraged Finance"},
        {"area": "Asset-Based Lending"},
        {"area": "Bankruptcy"}
    ],
    "Practise two": [
        {"area": "Corporate Governence"},
        {"area": "Derivatives"},
        {"area": "High Yield Offerings"}
    ],
    "Practise three": [
        {"area": "Electric Power Regulation"},
        {"area": "Export Control"},
        {"area": "FCPA"}
    ]
  },
    sel1 = $('#beta-filter1'),
    sel2 = $('#beta-filter2');

sel1.on('change', function() {
  $('option:gt(0)', sel2).remove();
  sel2.prop('disabled', true);
  if( this.selectedIndex > 0 ) {
    $.each( options[this.value], function() {
      sel2.append( $('<option/>',{text:this.area,value:this.area}) ).prop('disabled', false);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="beta-filter1" data-set="default" data-select="practise">
    <option label="Please select" value="">Please select</option>
    <option label="Practise one" value="Practise one">Practise one</option>
    <option label="Practise two" value="Practise two">Practise two</option>
    <option label="Practise three" value="Practise three">Practise three</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="beta-filter2" data-set="default" data-select="law" disabled>
    <option label="Please select" value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

**NOTE**:

If the JSON comes as you've indicated in your question, you could adjust it with a few lines of code before consuming it.

Comment: I just noticed that the Practise two and Practise three displays the same results in beta-filter2..

Comment: Fix your HTML and everything should be fine: it should be `value="Practise two"` for practise two not `value="Practise three"`.